# Activate bootstrap theme in BrowserTestBase phpunit test

Tags: theming, 8, testing

In a Drupal 8 testclass I am trying to install the [bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme (v 8.x-3.1). It is saved in the /theme directory. No problem when using the UI. Unfortunately I get an error in the test when I try to install it with this code:

```
/*
 * Anytest
 * @group proreos
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 *  
 */
class CalculatorControllerTest extends BrowserTestBase {

  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    \Drupal::service('theme_handler')->install(array('bootstrap'));
  }
```

The test exits with the following error:

```
PHPunit Test failed to complete; Error: PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian
Bergmann and contributors.
There was 1 error:

1)
Drupal\Tests\preosasde\Functional\CalculatorControllerTest::testCalculatorController
Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\SchemaIncompleteException: Schema errors for
bootstrap.settings with the following errors: bootstrap.settings:schemas
missing schema

/var/www/vhosts/proreos/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Testing/ConfigSchemaChecker.php:93
```

Any advice on this? Anyone tried to install bootstrap in an PHPUnit test sucessfully?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I just ran into something similar last week. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226501/simpletest-fails-with-invalid-database-prefix-no-other-information-given

Comment: Hm, I read the patch, thanks. But there is already a /themes/bootstrap/config/schema/bootstrap.schema.yml file in the bootstrap distro. So that's not the problem here.

Comment: The file exists, but it's basically empty and doesn't define anything: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bootstrap/tree/config/schema/bootstrap.schema.yml. schemas is not defined nor is anything else. You could disable schema validation, check the parent, but you should at least report this as a bug

Comment: bootstrap.schema.yml looks like bartik.schema.yml, it just doesn't declare any DB stuff because there's nothing to declare. I don't think it's a bootstrap bug. Do you know how to disable schema validation in PHPUnit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Berdir for the hint. The solution is to disable the schema validation here. It's done with this code in my testclass:

```
protected function getConfigSchemaExclusions() {
  return array_merge(parent::getConfigSchemaExclusions(), ['bootstrap.settings']);
}
```