# Test fails with custom configuration

Tags: testing

After creating a custom configuration for my module "module_name.settings.yml" simpletest fails with this message:

> InvalidArgumentException: Invalid database prefix: in Drupal\Core\Test\TestDatabase->__construct() (line 81 of /path/to/installation/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Test/TestDatabase.php)

I reinstalled my module and everything works. I load the configuration with the following code.

```
$config = \Drupal::config('module_name.settings');
$base = $config->get('module_name.variable');
```

Still, I can't run my tests. If I remove the content from my configuration, tests run again.
I'm using Drupal 8.3.4, Apache 2.4.18, PHP 7.0.8, and MariaDB 10.1.25.

Comment: What modules are listed for installing? I would bet a million dollars it is because one of the modules is missing a .schema.yml file under the config/schema dir.

Comment: @Kevin I don't think so, I can install my module. And if I remove the config file run tests properly.

Comment: Exactly. Because you removed the config file. I ran into the exact same thing earlier this year and patched Menu Breadcrumb to fix the error. Other modules missing a schema.yml file were also patched to fix this error. The error above is very misleading because it is not specific.

Comment: See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2848879  and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226501/simpletest-fails-with-invalid-database-prefix-no-other-information-given

Comment: That is to say, if you provide a settings file, you must provide a schema file too. But the opposite is not true (as far as I have seen).

Comment: @Kevin I think I own you a billion dollars now, you was right. A .schema.yml file was missing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yeah it threw me for a loop the first time because the error is totally not related at all. Only when I ran the same test from the command line did I get more insight that led me to the Schema issue. I will post as the answer.

Comment: @Kevin really strange that I can install my module but schema validator throws an error only on tests. Thanks you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your module provides a settings.yml file, it must also provide a mymodule.schema.yml file describing the config object that stores the settings.

The real error pertains to something along these lines, and not a database error:

```
The test did not complete due to a fatal error.
Exception Uncaught e ConfigSchemaCheck   86 Drupal\Core\Config\Testing\ConfigSc
    Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\SchemaIncompleteException: No schema for
    MODULENAME.settings in
    Drupal\Core\Config\Testing\ConfigSchemaChecker-&gt;onConfigSave() (line 86
    of
    /var/www/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Testing/ConfigSchemaChecker.php).
```

By providing a schema.yml file, clearing cache and re-running the tests this should resolve itself.

Related:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2848879
- [Simpletest fails with "invalid database prefix" - no other information given](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226501/simpletest-fails-with-invalid-database-prefix-no-other-information-given)

You have to be careful of this one, because any contrib module that provides a settings.yml without a matching schema will throw the same error. It is confusing because you can install the module in your main application, but when you install it with a test, it will error out.

It will be easy to narrow down which ones, because it will be one that is listed in your required modules var (`protected static $modules = [...]`) which is how I stumbled upon the Menu Breadcrumb issue I mentioned.